# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'admin'. in django

Tags: python, html, django, search, user-accounts

**i created this to make searchbox to search models, when i replace body instead of author it works perfectly and fetches data accurately but when i use foreign key object string input is not working but when i type pk of user it fetches the username accurately but does not accept string for eg: when i type name of the post it gets but on author when i type name of the author it says following error and does not accept string but can accept pk and fetch author**

**pls edit this code such that when i type name of the author it gets the name and their post**

**HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED**

1. views.py

   ```
      def search(request):
          query = request.GET['query']
          allposts = bio.objects.filter(author=query)
          params = {'allposts':allposts}
          return render(request,'profile_app/search.html',params)
   ```
2. models.py

   ```
    class bio(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        body = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   ```
3. search.html

   ```
   <h1>this is home</h1>
   <form action="/search" method="get">
   <input type="search" name="query">
   <button type="submit">press here</button>
   </form>
   ```

Comment: Just make something like ```allposts = bio.objects.filter(autor.email=query)```. It is normal that fk field accept only an id of the model. In docs you can find User attribute through which you can filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: Should be .filter(author__username=query). Attention to the double underscore

Comment: thank you dear smart devoloper for your kind help....